# Unable to boot freshly built CyanogenMod 13

Tags: android, boot, cyanogenmod, selinux

After playing around with the latest build of CM for my device (12.1), I decided to try and build my first ROM. So I got Linux, synced sources for 13, etc. (My device tree is [here.](https://github.com/aureljared/android_device_htc_enrc2b/))

I had to grapple with a few audio-related build errors before I finally got it to build. (If it makes any difference, all the commits I had to revert were related to PCM audio offloading.)

Now, when I try to boot the ROM, it immediately reboots to recovery without even displaying the boot animation. Looking at `/proc/last_kmsg`, the problem seems to be about SELinux:

```
...
[    4.340084] init: (Initializing SELinux enforcing took 0.51s.)
[    4.349071] type=1400 audit(1468237723.015:4): avc:  denied  { fowner } for  pid=1 comm="init" capability=3  scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0
[    4.349387] init: SELinux: Could not set context for /init:  Operation not permitted
[    4.349506] init: restorecon failed: Operation not permitted
[    4.349699] init: Security failure; rebooting into recovery mode...
[    4.350353] SysRq : Emergency Remount R/O (triggered by init:1)
[    4.350581] Emergency Remount complete
[    4.350889] reboot - triggered with task: init (1:1)
...
```

I'm not familiar with SELinux apart from the fact that it makes system modifications a lot harder, but from what I've seen, both the device-specific and general `init.te` files in the Android source allow `init` to use the `fowner` capability.

I've tried:

- Modifying the `sepolicy` file by making the `init` domain permissive
- Rebuilding the entire ROM with `permissive init;` in `init.te`
- Commenting out `restorecon /adb_keys` and `restorecon_recursive /mnt` in `init.rc`
- Rebuilding the device kernel with `EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_ALWAYS_ENFORCE=true`
- Searching for a solution on Google - a [person on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=63423225#post63423225) had the exact same problem as me but subsequent posts from him/her did not yield any progress or solutions on the matter

None of them made any difference, so basically, I'm fresh out of ideas.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you [installing](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_enrc2b) the ROM to your device correctly? And maybe the [build instructions](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_enrc2b) from CM might help (even if they are for a slightly older version). I assume you have the HTC One X+ because of the "enrc2b".

Comment: @Desirius Yes, I followed the instructions for building and installing (with a bit of modification - since the One X+ does not have S-OFF, TWRP cannot flash boot directly so I have to flash boot in fastboot myself) to no avail.